# Is it possible to define the success_url in django without kwargs

Tags: django, post, django-class-based-views

I am elaborating on the tutorial in the django docs to build a voting app. What I try to achieve is to be able to delete a candidate and, at success, get back to the detailview of the election. I know I could just add another parameter to the url like (full template below)

`<a href="{% url 'candidate_delete' c.id object.id %}" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash" class></a>`

I would like to know whether it is possible to use a post method (although there is no form). I did some research, found the 'next' parameter, but it does not get through. It looks like it needs a form, since all examples are using the 'next' within a form.

I also tried setting the success_url based on the election the to-be-deleted-candidate is ForeignKey-d to, but that generates the error:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /elections/candidate/delete/13/
>   The included URLconf '1' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

This is the view:

```
class CandidateDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Candidate
    template_name = 'election/delete.html'

    def get_object(self):
        obj = super().get_object()
        print(self.request.POST)
        election = Election.objects.get(id=obj.poll_id)
        if not election.owner_id == self.request.user.id:
            raise Http404
        return obj

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        obj = super().get_object()
        election = Election.objects.get(id=obj.poll_id)
        return reverse_lazy('election_detail', election.id)
```

The election_detail template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{{object.name}} - 
<ul>
   {% for c in candidate_list %}
  <h2>{{ c.name }}</h2>
    <li> {{ c.intro }} {{c.id}} 
        {{c.email}} 
        <a href="{% url 'candidate_delete' c.id %}" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash" class></a> <input type="hidden" name="next" value={{object.id}} />
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
    <a href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}" class="btn btn-primary" class>Back</a> 
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

the object in the template is the election that the candidates are linked to.

As you can see, I tried the post method, but, reading around, it seems to only work in a form. The success_url config throws an error as well.

Any help to use the post method or configure get_success_url with data from the model is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So, apparently, the reverse_lazy has to look like this:

```
    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        obj = super().get_object()
        election = Election.objects.get(id=obj.poll_id)
        return reverse_lazy('election_detail', kwargs={'pk':election.id})
```

While in the template, you can just add the var, in the return function you have to specify it is a kwargs.

I am almost sure the "election= .. "can be shorter, but that is for later